# R: Parametrization of covariance matrix with fixed elements

Tags: r, optimization, matrix, constraints, covariance

I'm making maximum likelihood estimation of certain gaussian model with unknown covariance matrix X which can contain fixed elements in arbitrary positions. When there is no fixed elements, I have been using following log-cholesky parametrization to ensure the positive semidefinity of X :

```
diag(X)<-exp(0.5*param[1:k]) 
X[lower.tri(X)]<-param[-(1:k)]
X<-crossprod(X)
```

If some of the rows and columns are fixed as zero, that is of course easily dealt by not updating those parts of the matrix:

```
nz<-diag(X)>0
diag(X)[nz]<-exp(0.5*param[1:k]) #different k now
X[nz,nz][lower.tri(X[nz,nz])]<-param[-(1:k)]
X[nz,nz]<-crossprod(X[nz,nz])
```

And this generalizes to whatever fixed row/column case. But what if only diagonal element of such row/column (ie. variance of the corresponding variable) is fixed, or only the correlation with some other variable? Is there any general way of doing this?

Here's an example of X, the NA's mark the elements I wan't to estimate whereas other element are fixed:

```
   > x
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
   [1,]   NA    0    0   NA   NA
   [2,]    0    0    0  0.0  0.0
   [3,]    0    0    1  0.0  0.0
   [4,]   NA    0    0   NA  0.5
   [5,]   NA    0    0  0.5   2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to simply ignore columns (or variables), you don't even need to recompute the Cholesky decomposition from scratch but efficiently down-grade it instead which you can do using orthogonal transformations e.g. Givens rotations. I would go about it by physically deleting the column and taking it from there.

Comment: I added an example of X to the original question. When some variable like second and third on in the example are have completely known variances and covariances with other variables, I can remove those rows and columns and work with the submatrix of X, but if I have fixed variance bot not covariances or other way around, this method can't be used.